# How to split a cell's formula based on functions using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a **working** formula in a cell:

`SUMIF(I_Income!$B:$B,'C_I&E (real)'!$B18,I_Income!T:T)+'C_SDev (real)'!T18+'C_Efficiency (real)'!T18`

and I'd like to know if it is possible to extract the `SUMIF` portion of this formula using VBA? So ignore the other gumph and just end up with a variable in VBA matching `SUMIF(I_Income!$B:$B,'C_I&E (real)'!$B18,I_Income!T:T)`.

So in summary, how do I ignore everything in the formula except for the `SUMIF` portion?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're after as I presume you're planning on doing this for more than the one cell. You can quite happily use `Range.Formula` and then if you know the part of the string you want to take out then you could use string functions to pull that bit out and assign that to a variable, or get a function that generates that part of your formula. Apologies for the meandering answer but I'm just not too clear on your issue.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  You can use the `.Formula` property and the `Split` function

Comment: @TimEdwards it's pretty explicit no? I want to extract just the `SumIf` portion of that formula into a variable. How would I ignore the other elements and just pickup the `SumIf`?

Comment: Like Tim said, step1 extract the formula with Range.Formula, step2 use string functions (here's I'd recommed the Left of the Pos('C_SDev)) to extract the part of the formula you want.

Comment: Use `MID` to the `FIND`  or `INSTR` of the first `+` should do for the example?

Comment: Use `Instr(Range().Formula,"SUMIF")` to find out where it starts. Then you'll have to work out where it ends, if you've got brackets inside the SUMIF bit then you'll probably have to go through the string doing +1 for `(` and -1 for `)` until you get to the point that the relevant bracket deems the end of the `SUMIF` formula. Then just use a `MID` to get that bit.